# Pyenv seems to cause the "wrong" spark executable to run. How to fix it?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyenv

I cannot seem to get pyspark working nicely with pyenv. Running pyspark whilst a virtualenv is activated fails. Calling the "right" binary directly seems to work.

```
(anaconda3-5.3.0) ➜  ~ which pyspark
/Users/cammil/.pyenv/shims/pyspark
(anaconda3-5.3.0) ➜  ~ pyspark
Error executing Jupyter command '/Users/cammil/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.0/bin/find_spark_home.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/Users/cammil/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.0/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/cammil/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.0/bin/pyspark: line 77: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/Users/cammil/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.0/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
(anaconda3-5.3.0) ➜  ~ /usr/local/bin/pyspark
# this launches a jupyter notebook and all seems to work...
```

What am I doing wrong?